# Comparing lists with objects

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have 2 lists

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
```

and a dictionary

```
dict = {'SNo': 1, 'Data': "Random Data"}
```

Let the list1, list2 contain multiple instances of this dictionary with different SNo and data. Some of the SNo may be same. But the Data need not be.

I want to merge (and sort) these 2 lists based on the SNo , maintaining their structure while ignoring the ones with the same SNo.

**Assumption:** If the list of dictionaries have the same SNo, then list2's entry is ignored.

Comment: What is an “instance of this dictionary”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = [{'SNo': 1, 'Data': "abc"} , {'SNo': 2, 'Data': "bcd"}, {'SNo': 2, 'Data': "def"}]
list2 = [{'SNo': 3, 'Data': "abc"} , {'SNo': 4, 'Data': "bcd"}, {'SNo': 3, 'Data': "def"}]

# to keep merged lists
final_list = []

# this list will track if sno exit alreay
sno_list = []

# take evry dict from combined list:
for d in list1+list2:
  # extract sno 
  sno = d['SNo']
  # if sno not present in sno_list add that sno.
  if sno not in sno_list:
    # add evry dict , if its sno not present in the sno_list.
    final_list.append(d)
    sno_list.append(sno)

print(final_list)    

#[{'SNo': 1, 'Data': 'abc'}, {'SNo': 2, 'Data': 'bcd'}, {'SNo': 3, 'Data': 'abc'}, {'SNo': 4, 'Data': 'bcd'}]

#sorting list

result = sorted(final_list,key=lambda d:d['SNo'])
#[{'SNo': 1, 'Data': 'abc'}, {'SNo': 2, 'Data': 'bcd'}, {'SNo': 3, 'Data': 'abc'}, {'SNo': 4, 'Data': 'bcd'}]
print(result)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I didn't know you can merge a list by using the '+' operator. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sorted builtin func to do that,

```
    sorted(list1+list2, key=lambda x: x['SNo'])
```

Each item is sorted based on the value returned from the lambda function. For each item now the list will sorted based on the value of 'id' in each.You can also sort in reverse order

```
    sorted(list1+list2, key=lambda x: x['SNo'], reverse=True)
```

Note: This might not ignore duplicate value of "SNo". You can remove it after obtaining the sorted merged list